# Copying sheets from various workbooks and pasting into a sheet in a different workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have 7 workbooks which are all of an identical format on each sheet. I want to grab "Sheet2" from each of the workbooks and paste them into a master sheet in a separate workbook. I have managed to do this but the pasting keeps overwriting the the last paste. How can I paste below the last pasted entry?

I have this for each of the 7 sheets

```
Sub MoveHR()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("\\ukkh1-afp-sv1o\Shared\Sales\Field Sales - 

ERN\DSRs\. DSR's February 2016\HRehman February.xlsm")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("\\ukkh1-afp-sv1o\Shared\Sales\Field Sales - ERN\DSRs\Trackers\SIMPosa Tracker.xlsm")

'Now, copy what you want from x:
x.Sheets("SIMPosa").Range("A:J").Copy

'Now, paste to y worksheet:
y.Sheets("Current Month").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Close x:
Application.CutCopyMode = False
x.Close False
y.Close True
End Sub
```

Comment: Slightly offtopic: I would suggest you always write out your commands, even if you technically don't have to. It makes your code easier to read and once you start writing longer code, it might really help you. So I'd suggest to write: x.Close SaveChanges:=False

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a loop to find the next empty row, like this:

```
dim i as integer
i=1

do until y.sheets("Current Month").cells(i,1).value=""
    i=i+1
loop

y.Sheets("Current Month").Cells(i,1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
y.Sheets("Current Month").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

to this:

```
y.Sheets("Current Month").Range("A" & y.Sheets("Current Month").Rows.Count).End(xlup).Offset(1)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

The 2nd line is the equivalent of going to the last row in the sheet and hitting `Ctrl+Up` and to find the last row with data, then offsetting that by 1 row to paste the new data.